# Is there a way to overload Lua's boolean test?

Tags: lua

I want to overload Lua's boolean test operator (eg `if foo then ...`). Looking through the 5.1 source it looks like `lua_toboolean()` does not have a corresponding metamethod, and there doesn't seem to be any other obvious way. Is there a way? If not, does anyone know if this is by design or a simple oversight?

Comment: what do you really want to do? why do you need to overload it?

Comment: I have a proxy layer that exposes certain engine objects to Lua. Its possible for those objects to be destroyed while Lua is still holding a reference. In that case the Lua-side object becomes invalid. Its no problem for the proxy layer to implement a `foo:isvalid()` method or similar, but it would read much better to simply write `if foo then ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately (or, rather, fortunately) there is no good and sane method of doing this.

See http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaVirtualization